# Hibernate left join fetch on many returns duplicities

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have a problem, I am using Hibernate via Spring data and I have this data model (model is much bigger but this is the part that causes problems).

Lets assume we have `Entity A` and `Entity B`.
Relationship between two entities are **Many-to-Many**.

I am trying to fetch **A** records with `B` recordes **fetched** (to prevent lazy loading).

The model is connected like this

On entity A:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items")
private List<BEntity> bs = new ArrayList<>();
```

On entity B

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "a_b",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }
)
private Collection<AEntity> as = new ArrayList<>();
```

So its typical M:N relationship. And I am trying to retrieve A data like following

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM AEntity a " +
        "   LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bs" +
        "WHERE a.id IN (:aIds)")
List<AEntity> findX(@NonNull @Param("aIds") Collection<Long> aIds);
```

The resulted SQL is something like

```
select X -- select fields omitted for simplicity
from item itembo0_
         left outer join a_b ab on a.id = ab.a_id
         left outer join b b on ab.b_id = b.id
where a.id in (...)
```

Which is a thing I would expect. The SQL will result duplicites (which I would expect as well cause there might be many B records which each has one result row). But at the end, **hibernate does not merge all these rows into a A entity with fetched B fields**.

For example, when I pass a 5 IDS into "in" condition, I get a 10 A records. **Each one has a 2 B records linked! Thats the weird part**.

Is there anyone who can tell me why hibernate does not merge these SQL results by A.id identifier and makes duplicites? Is it because I am asking for a List instead of Set?

Comment: Did you implement a proper `equals` and `hashCode`? See https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/. Also you might want to do a `SELECT DISTINCT a ... ` in your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the "DISTINCT" keyword in your query should be enough to avoid duplicates:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM AEntity a " +
        "   LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bs" +
        "WHERE a.id IN (:aIds)")
List<AEntity> findX(@NonNull @Param("aIds") Collection<Long> aIds);
```

I do not know what kind of data you store, but perhaps a better solution, as you have mentioned, would be to use a Set instead of a List.

Comment: Hi, DISTINCT works, but I would like to understand why Hibernate can not process these children records as in case of 1:M relation, the result of SQL with 1:M relation has duplicates as well but Hibernate correctly merge all rows with primary key of FROM entity together and creates Entity object.

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem is on the Hibernate side. The official documentation says: "Queries that make use of eager fetching of collections usually return duplicates of the root objects, but with their collections initialized. You can filter these duplicates through a Set." [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying-executing)

Comment: Well the default ManyToMany Fetch is LAZY. Returning SET (or using distinct) works fine buts its still kind of a workaround. I would like to Hibernate to be able to JOIN FETCH many childrens without duplicates (as it does in case of 1:M)

Comment: This is wierd. Using a subselect will return the correct values but the subselect is not going to be as  fast.